# MagJack for PoE Powered Device

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, rectifier, poe, rj45

I am adding `Power over Ethernet` functionality in my `Toradex's` System-on-module ([Colibri iMX6ULL](https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules/colibri-arm-family/nxp-imx6ull?gclid=Cj0KCQjwof3cBRD9ARIsAP8x70PBdY0ckWmZtWre-9pHRI0pG_khgozle-ph6G7JKrvjqKHSA9YjULoaAsvEEALw_wcB)) based carrier-board design. I am having confusion in selecting the `MagJack` for the design. I want to implement `Mode A` and `Mode B`. However, It would be great if someone can comment on the designs for `4-pair mode`.

The MagJack that I am considering is [SI-52003-F](https://belfuse.com/resources/drawings/magneticsolutions/dr-mag-si-52003-f.pdf). The schematics presented in their datasheet has been posted below:

[image]

Since, the schematics shows center-tap on network side of the transformer and the Power Pins are brought out. I think it will work for my application but I am not 100% sure. The rectification designs that I am considering are given below:

[image]

Design 1 is simplest and requires less space and components. It assumes the pinout and polarity as given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet).

[image]

Design 2 assumes the polarity can be different and makes sure non-IEEE 802.3af PSE works with my PCB.

My earlier version of the PCB (without PoE) has a MagJack (without centre-tap transformer). The Ethernet part of the schematics is below: (R19 is unassembled)

[image]

My questions are:

1. What would be best Design (1 or 2) for my application?
2. The MagJack that I have been considering, Is it suitable for PoE (Mode A and Mode B both)?
3. The last question could be a stupid question but still I want to be sure before proceeding further. I was using this [MagJack](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/pulse-electronics-network/J00-0065NL/553-1345-ND/1036961) in earlier version of my PCB and it was working perfectly. However, I am moving with SI-52003-f Magjack for PoE capabilities. Will it make any difference for the Ethernet Controller if I switch the MagJack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be best Design (1 or 2) for my application?

Design 2 gives your system more tolerance for miswiring, which is a good thing.  These days it's generally not necessary to pay attention to whether wiring is straight-through or crossed over, because with widely available gigabit and auto-MDI/X the hardware just figures it out.  Design 2 will be similarly tolerant, and will work even if pairs are crossed over or otherwise mixed up.

> The MagJack that I have been considering, Is it suitable for PoE (Mode A and Mode B both)?

It appears to be designed to support PoE, given the way the center taps and extra pairs are brought out and labeled in the schematic.

> The last question could be a stupid question but still I want to be sure before proceeding further. I was using this MagJack in earlier version of my PCB and it was working perfectly. However, I am moving with SI-52003-f Magjack for PoE capabilities. Will it make any difference for the Ethernet Controller if I switch the MagJack?

No, it won't make any difference.  Ethernet magnetics are all pretty much designed to do the same thing, and the PHY will be designed to tolerate a wide range of cabling characteristics anyway, so the magnetics will make little difference by comparison.